# how can we deny transfer of stock move if qty > order qty?

Tags: odoo, transfer, stock

the new stock management in odoo allow to transfer more than commanded quantity!

how can we deny *do_detailed_transfer* in *stock.picking* when the **quantity** **> order.quantity** ?

Comment: You have to create a module (or modify the code of Odoo core) that extend the object 'stock.transfert_details'. In this extended object, redefined the method 'do_detailed_transfer' to check the processed quantity and raise an error if the processed qty is more than the commanded qty.

Answer (score 0):

raise an warrning if there is extra moves like: 
**raise osv.except_osv(_('Warning !'),
                                                 _(u'The quantity is more than validate quantity !!') )**

```
    @api.cr_uid_ids_context
    def do_transfer(self, cr, uid, picking_ids, context=None):
        """
            If no pack operation, we do simple action_done of the picking
            Otherwise, do the pack operations
        """
        if not context:
            context = {}
        stock_move_obj = self.pool.get('stock.move')
        for picking in self.browse(cr, uid, picking_ids, context=context):
            if not picking.pack_operation_ids:
                self.action_done(cr, uid, [picking.id], context=context)
                continue
            else:
                need_rereserve, all_op_processed = self.picking_recompute_remaining_quantities(cr, uid, picking, context=context)
                #create extra moves in the picking (unexpected product moves coming from pack operations)
                todo_move_ids = []
                if not all_op_processed:
                    todo_move_ids += self._create_extra_moves(cr, uid, picking, context=context)
                    **raise osv.except_osv(_('Warning !'),
                                             _(u'The quantity is more than validate quantity !!') )**
                #split move lines if needed
                toassign_move_ids = []
                for move in picking.move_lines:
                    remaining_qty = move.remaining_qty
                    if move.state in ('done', 'cancel'):
                        #ignore stock moves cancelled or already done
                        continue
                    elif move.state == 'draft':
                        toassign_move_ids.append(move.id)
                    if float_compare(remaining_qty, 0,  precision_rounding = move.product_id.uom_id.rounding) == 0:
                        if move.state in ('draft', 'assigned', 'confirmed'):
                            todo_move_ids.append(move.id)
                    elif float_compare(remaining_qty,0, precision_rounding = move.product_id.uom_id.rounding) > 0 and \
                                float_compare(remaining_qty, move.product_qty, precision_rounding = move.product_id.uom_id.rounding) < 0:
                        raise osv.except_osv(_('Warning !'),
                                             _(u'La quantity doit être inferieur à %s'% move.product_qty) )
                        return False
                        new_move = stock_move_obj.split(cr, uid, move, remaining_qty, context=context)
                        todo_move_ids.append(move.id)
                        #Assign move as it was assigned before
                        toassign_move_ids.append(new_move)
                if need_rereserve or not all_op_processed: 
                    if not picking.location_id.usage in ("supplier", "production", "inventory"):
                        self.rereserve_quants(cr, uid, picking, move_ids=todo_move_ids, context=context)
                    self.do_recompute_remaining_quantities(cr, uid, [picking.id], context=context)
                if todo_move_ids and not context.get('do_only_split'):
                    self.pool.get('stock.move').action_done(cr, uid, todo_move_ids, context=context)
                elif context.get('do_only_split'):
                    context = dict(context, split=todo_move_ids)
            self._create_backorder(cr, uid, picking, context=context)
            if toassign_move_ids:
                stock_move_obj.action_assign(cr, uid, toassign_move_ids, context=context)
        return True
```